# XDebug is not detected by PHPstorm

Tags: php, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

I have Installed nginx and php-fpm, in order to load php codes from nginx, my page works fine, but now I want to run xdebug in order to debug my code.

I follow the steps from the manuals, I modified my php.ini inside from my php-fpm folder (that is a must) but as you can see in the picture my route to the fpm does does not appear, so it believe that XDebug is not installed, when really it is.

Open Settings->Languages & Frameworks->PHP

[Open Settings->Languages & Frameworks->PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNjpA.png)

Thank you so much

Comment: Your nginx may force/configured PHP to use different php.ini for web requests than what is used for CLI request (lots of Linux distros and even Mac uses such approach). Please show the `phpinfo()` output captured via browser (the top header part should be enough -- it should show the xdebug there). Quite possible you are editing the wrong php.ini.

Comment: The problem it is that I it can't detect the php.ini that I it is on the fpm folder.

Comment: No idea what you are saying. You have not provided any screenshots or any other output that would confirm your words / the actual situations there.

Comment: the php.ini that belongs to the php-fpm (necessary for my project) is in the path /etc/php5/fpm, but the path that I cant that php.ini that php storms are in /etc/php5/cli/. the debbuger is detected  by the the server that interest me(nginx with php-fpm). I just want to change the route that php storm says from etc/php5/cli to etc/php5/fpm.

Comment: The thing is -- the PHP interpreters (be it local or remote via SSH like yours) is to be run in CLI environment. It's PHP that decides what php.ini to use (when run it sees that it get called via CLI it uses appropriate config) + PhpStorm itself has no settings that would allow to specify what php.ini the interpreter should be using.

Comment: Therefore: 1) If you need to debug web pages via browser .. then you do not even need the interpreter defined (IDe will not call your PHP directly here -- all done by web server; the debugger engine used can be specified at `PHP | Servers` settings page) 2) if you want to execute/debug scripts over SSH (which is a CLI environment; here IDE calls your PHP directly) -- then you will need to edit your php.ini that is used by CLI environment and not php-fpm.

Comment: The thing it is that I need php-fpm because is how my page works, for sure

Comment: Once again -- what and how do you want to debug: a web page via browser or a CLI script over SSH?

Comment: I understand that -- you want to debug PHP (otherwise we would not be talking about PHP and xdebug, right?). So please -- read again and answer my question.

Comment: In my company we use Xdebug to debug php code from a remote host

Comment: I'm sorry to say but your answers are not helping here at all -- they are not answering my question at all.

Comment: Didnt you see a PHP code with xdebug??

Comment: 1) http://xdebug.org/docs/ 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne I just had to deactivate the firewall and now works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem, PHP Storm is supposed to detect the debuggers if the configuration files is correct, BUT is importat to make sure that the firewall doesn't block the ports used.

To prove that I deactivated the firewall and now works fine.

Comment: PD: If you need to use a firewall make sure to configure the firewall and PHP Storm with the port that you want to use in your machine.